# Ошибка при определении функции шаблона вне класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, vector

```
template <typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>  
struct vector {
    using iterator = T*;
    //
    iterator insert(iterator p, const T& val);
    //
private:
    int sz;  //Размер (кол-во элементов)
    T* elem; //Указатель на элементы 
    int space; //Размер выделенной памяти 
    A alloc; //Работает с памятью, выделяемой для элементов
};
```

Определение функции вне класса

```
template <typename T, typename A = allocator<T>> 
vector<T,A>::iterator vector<T, A>::insert(iterator p, const T& val) {
    //Реализация
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "iterator"

Не могу понять, как исправить и в чём причина (Справка из google не помогла)

Если меняю возвращаемое значение на T* - работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить `typename`, так как `iterator` является зависимым (от параметров шаблона) типом, кроме того нельзя переопределять значение для параметра шаблона по-умолчанию:

```
template <typename T, typename A> 
typename vector<T,A>::iterator vector<T, A>::insert(iterator p, const T& val)
{
   //Реализация
}
```

Как альтернативу, можно использовать хвостовое возвращаемое значение:

```
template <typename T, typename A> 
auto vector<T, A>::insert(iterator p, const T& val) -> iterator
{
   //Реализация
}
```

Comment: А можно и хвост обрубить, оставив одно `auto`.